# What's the difference between char *a[]={"hello", "world"}; and char a[][10]={"hello", "world"};?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, declaration, implicit-conversion

When I tried out this code

```
char *a[] = {"hello", "world" };
char **p = a;
char a[][10]={"hello", "world"};
```

My compilation fails and I am told that there is a conflicting type error for the variable a. How is the top declaration, different from the bottom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a picture of memory layout. This corresponds to the code:

```
char *a[2] = { "hello", "world" };
char **p = a;
char b[][10] = { "hello", "world" };
char **q = b;   // Error
```

[image: Memory layout diagram]

Red = character array, Green = pointer-to-char, Teal = pointer-to-pointer-to-char.

A `char **` (i.e. a pointer to `char *`) can only point at `char *` variables, it cannot point at a char array .

As you can see, the `char **` called `p` is pointing to storage of a `char *`.

But where can `q` point? There are no variables of the right type.  If you want to point directly at `b`, or at rows of `b`, then you need a pointer which points to char arrays (not a pointer which points to char pointers).

Answer (score 6):

In the first declaration

```
char *a[] = {"hello", "world" };
```

the array `a` has the type `char * [2]`. Elements of the array have the type `char *`.

Used in expressions as for example as an initializer it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element that has the type `char **`,

So this declaration

```
char **p = a;
```

is correct.

This declaration

```
char a[][10]={"hello", "world"};
```

declares an array of the type `char [2][10]`. Elements of the array have the type `char[10]`.

Used in expressions it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `char ( * )[10]`.

So the correct declaration of the pointer will be

```
char ( *p )[10] = a;
```

Thus the two declarations of arrays declare arrays of different types.

Pay attention to that you may not change string literals using elements (pointers) of the first array.

In the second declaration the elements of the literal are copied into elements of the array. As the array does not have the qualifier `const` then you may change the stored strings.